# how to reformat a dict python

Tags: python, dictionary, format

I'm stuck on an issue with trying to re-format a dict

Here's my code that is writing the dict:

```
deLimit = "**"
hashKey = item1 +deLimit+ item2 +deLimit+ item3 +deLimit+ item4

mydict[hashKey] = {
   “key”: currentTotal + 1
                    }

with open(file,’a’) as newfile:
    print “heading1 heading2 heading3 heading4 heading5”
    for key, val in myDict.iteritems():
       print(repr((key.split('**'), val)))
```

Results in:

```
heading1 heading2 heading3 heading4 heading5
([‘item1’, ‘item2’, ‘item3’, ‘item4’], {‘key’: 1})
([‘item1’, ‘item2’, ‘item3’, ‘item4’], {‘key’: 1})
([‘item1’, ‘item2’, ‘item3’, ‘item4’], {‘key’: 1})
```

I know that **repr** makes a nice format of my dict. But how do I re-format the output?

What I’m looking to achieve is:

```
heading1 heading2 heading3 heading4 heading5
item1 item2 item3 item4 keyValue
item1 item2 item3 item4 keyValue
item1 item2 item3 item4 keyValue
item1 item2 item3 item4 keyValue
item1 item2 item3 item4 keyValue
…
```

But I’m not sure how to re-format this output

```
([‘item1’, ‘item2’, ‘item3’, ‘item4’], {‘key’: 1})
```

Thanks

Comment: You don't. You iterate the structures and generate your own output.

Comment: what is structure of `myDict` ?

Comment: what's your "myDict" look like?

Comment: @HarperKoo added code to show myDict

Comment: @Rohanil added code to show myDict

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
for key, val in myDict.iteritems():
    print (key.replace('**', ' ') + ' ' + str(val['key']))
```

Comment: Let me try and walk this back, let me know if this is correct So key.replace, is removing my asterisk anywhere within the key and adding a space. then a space is added in before the value of the key is printed.

Answer (score 1):

```
for key, val in mydict.items():
    print(",".join(key.split('**')),val['key'],sep=",")
```

Comment: I get this error :   
`print(",".join(key.split('**')),val['hits'],sep=",")
                                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

not sure how to format this response, but the carrot is under "sep" saying that its invalid syntax

Comment: my python version is 3.5, maybe that's the reason.

Comment: for python 2.x, you can change it like: `print " ".join(key.split('**')), str(val['key'])`